# .each js causing issues with other classes on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

**HTML**

```
<ul class="courseDates">
    <li class="dateOne col-sm-2">
        {tag_course date 1}
    </li>
    <li class="dateTwo col-sm-2">
        {tag_course date 2}
    </li>
    <li class="dateThree col-sm-2">
        {tag_course date 3}
    </li>
    <li class="dateFour col-sm-2">
        {tag_course date 4}
    </li>
    <li class="dateFive col-sm-2">
        {tag_course date 5}
    </li>
</ul>
```

**Javascript**

```
$('.dateOne').each(function() {    
    var data =jQuery(this).text();
    var arr = data.split('-');
    jQuery(this).html('<a class="button '+arr[1] + '" href="/training-rego?trainingDate={tag_course date 1}&trainingName={tag_name_nolink}&courseId={tag_itemid}"> <span class="day">'+arr[0] + '</span> <span class="month">'+arr[1] + '</span> <span  class="year">'+arr[2] + '</span> </a>');            
}); 

$('.dateTwo').each(function() {    
    var data =jQuery(this).text();
    var arr = data.split('-');
    jQuery(this).html('<a class="button '+arr[1] + '" href="/training-rego?trainingDate={tag_course date 2}&trainingName={tag_name_nolink}&courseId={tag_itemid}"> <span class="day">'+arr[0] + '</span> <span class="month">'+arr[1] + '</span> <span  class="year">'+arr[2] + '</span> </a>');            
}); 

$('.dateThree').each(function() {    
    var data =jQuery(this).text();
    var arr = data.split('-');
    jQuery(this).html('<a class="button '+arr[1] + '" href="/training-rego?trainingDate={tag_course date 3}&trainingName={tag_name_nolink}&courseId={tag_itemid}"> <span class="day">'+arr[0] + '</span> <span class="month">'+arr[1] + '</span> <span  class="year">'+arr[2] + '</span> </a>');            
});

$('.dateFour').each(function() {    
    var data =jQuery(this).text();
    var arr = data.split('-');
    jQuery(this).html('<a class="button '+arr[1] + '" href="/training-rego?trainingDate={tag_course date 4}&trainingName={tag_name_nolink}&courseId={tag_itemid}"> <span class="day">'+arr[0] + '</span> <span class="month">'+arr[1] + '</span> <span  class="year">'+arr[2] + '</span> </a>');            
}); 

$('.dateFive').each(function() {    
    var data =jQuery(this).text();
    var arr = data.split('-');
    jQuery(this).html('<a class="button '+arr[1] + '" href="/training-rego?trainingDate={tag_course date 5}&trainingName={tag_name_nolink}&courseId={tag_itemid}"> <span class="day">'+arr[0] + '</span> <span class="month">'+arr[1] + '</span> <span  class="year">'+arr[2] + '</span> </a>');            
});
```

I need to remove the `.each` so the code operates for each item, the .each is causing undefined errors in other items on the page. It needs to be individual, so it outputs specific tags per group of dates, the `.each` function make the last item on the page work, but then has undefined errors on the first item .

[Here](http://techserve01.businesscatalyst.com/training-categories/hazardous-areas) is a working version, so you can check it.

Is there a better way to write the JS?

Any help regarding this matter would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Is `{tag_course date 1}` replaced by something? You'rebetter off having that in the question as you're splitting by `-` and that does not appear in this text at all.

Comment: Yes, so there might be 5 courses on the page, each course has a field to enter a Course Date 1 then there is a template for each course, when it's generated on the front end of the site it spits out the date for each one. does that make sense? @Jamiec

Comment: Side note but try to be consistent in the way you use jQuery, you use both `$()` and `jQuery()` when there is no need for it.

Comment: @GillesC true, I took 2 codes and mashed them together myself, I'm not very good with Javascript, I know what I want it do and It's probably not that complicated but I just don't know how to execute it properly

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

HTML

```
<ul class="courseDates">
    <li class="date col-sm-2">
        {tag_course date 1}
    </li>
    <li class="date col-sm-2">
        {tag_course date 2}
    </li>
    <li class="date col-sm-2">
        {tag_course date 3}
    </li>
    <li class="date col-sm-2">
        {tag_course date 4}
    </li>
    <li class="date col-sm-2">
        {tag_course date 5}
    </li>
</ul>
```

Javascript

```
$('.date').each(function(index) {    
    var data =jQuery(this).text();
    var arr = data.split('-');
    jQuery(this).html('<a class="button '+arr[1] + '" href="/training-rego?trainingDate={tag_course date ' + index + '}&trainingName={tag_name_nolink}&courseId={tag_itemid}"> '+arr[0] + ' '+arr[1] + ' '+arr[2] + ' </a>');           
});
```

Comment: the .each is causing undifined issues on this page http://techserve01.businesscatalyst.com/training-categories/hazardous-areas 

click LVR CPR these date buttons work properly, click on one and it will take you to the rego form page and pass the selected course date to the rego page. then click on a date button under 'HV 4 Competency Cluster' the you'll see the LVR CPR date still gets passed through

Comment: Are you using the same classname **date** for other elements also?

Answer (score 0):

You're simply overcomplicating this, just make them all have one shared class (eg `date`) and run the `.each` code just once. They all do the same behaviour which is

- Split the date in the `li` by a hyphen
- use the date part as a class on the `<button>`
- Wrap the date with a link.

See working code below and view source to see the transformation.

```js
$('.date').each(function() {  
    var $this = $(this);  
    var data =$this.text();
    var arr = data.split('-');
    $this.html('<a class="button '+arr[1] + '" href="/training-rego?trainingDate={tag_course date 5}&trainingName={tag_name_nolink}&courseId={tag_itemid}"> '+arr[0] + ' '+arr[1] + ' '+arr[2] + ' </a>');           
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="courseDates">
  <li class="date col-sm-2">
    14-Dec-2016
  </li>
  <li class="date col-sm-2">
    15-Dec-2016
  </li>
  <li class="date col-sm-2">
    16-Dec-2016
  </li>
  <li class="date col-sm-2">
    24-Dec-2016
  </li>
  <li class="date col-sm-2">
    29-Dec-2016
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: the .each is causing undifined issues on this page [Working Version](http://techserve01.businesscatalyst.com/training-categories/hazardous-areas) click LVR CPR these date buttons work properly, click on one and it will take you to the rego form page and pass the selected course date to the rego page. then click on a date button under 'HV 4 Competency Cluster' the you'll see the LVR CPR date still gets passed through

Comment: @Jake that has nothing to do with your javascript and has to do with your server-side code building up the `ul`'s I suspect.

Comment: @Jake oh, no wait its because you're including the javascript twice. One for each of your tabs. Yeah, dont do that.

Comment: It can't be done any other way, otherwise the dates won't get passed through for each date button, I want this JS to operate independently for each tab

Comment: Have a look now, [Working Version](http://techserve01.businesscatalyst.com/training-categories/hazardous-areas) I've bypassed the .each by giving the date buttons unique classes, this has fixed the problem , click a date button in each course and the correct data is now passed to the Rego Form page

Does it make sense what I'm trying to do, while I know it's working now, there must be a way to simplify the original JS to not look for each?

Comment: sorry for sounding like an amauture, JS really isn't my strong point